# Here map sdk to react native component

Tags: android, react-native

I have a problem with Here map sdk. Im trying to create a compmonent from native side and call from react native side. But i'm having this problem. I cant get the map initilize. 
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcfaH.png)

I get this error from emulator.

These are my codes :

**HereMapView.java :**

```
public class HereMapView extends MapViewLite {
    private static final String TAG = HereMapView.class.getSimpleName();
    private MapViewLite mapView;

    public HereMapView(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        loadMapScene();
    }


    private void loadMapScene() {
        // Load a scene from the SDK to render the map with a map style.
        mapView.getMapScene().loadScene(MapStyle.NORMAL_DAY, new MapScene.LoadSceneCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadScene(@Nullable MapScene.ErrorCode errorCode) {
                if (errorCode == null) {
                    mapView.getCamera().setTarget(new GeoCoordinates(52.530932, 13.384915));
                    mapView.getCamera().setZoomLevel(14);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onLoadScene failed: " + errorCode.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        this.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        this.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        this.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

**HereMapManager.java :**

```
public class HereMapManager  extends ViewGroupManager<HereMapView> {
    private static final String TAG = HereMapManager.class.getSimpleName();
    static final String REACT_CLASS = "HereMapView";
    public Activity activity;
    public HereMapManager(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    protected HereMapView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new HereMapView(reactContext);
    }
}
```

**HereMapModule.java :**

```
public class HereMapModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    private static final String TAG = HereMapModule.class.getSimpleName();

    HereMapModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "HereMapView";
    }
    public Activity getActivity() {
        return getCurrentActivity();
    }

    public static void closeQuietly(Closeable closeable) {
        if (closeable == null) return;
        try {
            closeable.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

**HereMapPackage :**

```
public class HereMapPackage implements ReactPackage {
    protected Activity activity;
    public HereMapPackage() {
    }

    public HereMapPackage(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    } // backwards compatibility
    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Arrays.<NativeModule>asList(new HereMapModule(reactContext));
    }

    public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        //HereMapManager mapManager = new HereMapManager(reactContext);
        HereMapManager mapManager = new HereMapManager(this.activity);
        return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(mapManager);
    }
}
```

then i adding the package to :
**MainAplication.java :**

```
@Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
            packages.add(new HereMapPackage());
          return packages;
        }
```

with this function.

And then i call from react native side with this code :

**App.js :**

```
const HereMapView = requireNativeComponent('HereMapView');
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.screen}>
        <HereMapView style={{flex : 1}} />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Can you help me please? Im stuck over a 2 week in this.

Comment: I don't think the code you posted for HereMapView.java matches the stack trace you posted because the trace mentions line 46 but what you posted only has 45 lines of code

Comment: Here's hint. Look at the first line of the routine loadMapScene.  What is the value of the member mapView when you call mapView.getMapScene()?

Comment: I didn't include in the code library imports. That's why 45 lines of code exist. I didn't want to crowded the code.

Comment: Kind of makes it difficult to match up line numbers doesn't it?